# No transparency in ImageView in AppWidget on Android devices below Api23

Tags: android, imageview, picasso, android-glide, android-appwidget

When i try to load an external PNG with transparency from Webserver using Glide (or picasso) transparency color becomes white on devices < api23 (6.0).
On devices running >=api23 everything is ok.

I have no idea how to solve that.

example code:

```
 AppWidgetTarget widgetTarget = new AppWidgetTarget(context, remoteViews, R.id.widget_map,widgetId);
 Glide.with(context.getApplicationContext()).load(url).asBitmap()
      .placeholder(errorPlaceholder)
      .error(errorPlaceholder)
      .into(widgetTarget);
```

Comment: I've not encountered this before but ImageView is a fairly lightweight class with, I'm sure, a lot of functionality you won't be using - why not write a short custom view that manages the drawing of the bitmap itself?